# Update ELF shared object generated with "-Bsymbolic" linker option

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries, elf

I believe that "-Bsymbolic" options adds a flag in ELF dynamic symbol table of the shared object.

Is there any way to remove this flag using tools like objcopy, make it behave as a shared object built without "-Bsymbolic" flag? I wont be able to re-build the library that is built with the said flag.

More info:

- Compiler: gcc
- Platform: arm linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `-Bsymbolic` cannot be undone.  The reason is that the link editor applies relaxations which eliminate certain relocations.  For example, consider this source code, to be compiled into a shared object:

```
int f1(void) { }
int f2(void) { f1(); }
```

If compiled and linked with `gcc-O2 -shared -fpic`, there is an `R_X86_64_JUMP_SLOT` relocation:

```
Relocation section '.rela.plt' at offset 0x510 contains 1 entries:
    Offset             Info             Type               Symbol's Value  Symbol's Name + Addend
0000000000201018  0000000800000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLOT     0000000000000670 f1 + 0
```

This comes from the call to `f1` in `f2`, which has to go through the PLT to enable interposition:

```
0000000000000670 <f1>:
 670:   repz retq
 672:   nopl   0x0(%rax)
 676:   nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)

0000000000000680 <f2>:
 680:   jmpq   550 <f1@plt>
```

If compiled and linked with `-O2 -shared -fpic -Wl,-Bsymbolic`, it is gone completely because the link editor was able to resolve the reference and use a direct jump to `f1`:

```
0000000000000650 <f1>:
 650:   repz retq
 652:   nopl   0x0(%rax)
 656:   nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)

0000000000000660 <f2>:
 660:   jmpq   650 <f1>
```

There is no automated way to put back a PLT into the shared object.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation Florian, much appreciated. I wasn't completely aware of what happens under the hood when -Bsymbolic is added. Now, I'm able to get a better picture of it.